# Hide post-function calls in with statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, raii

I have a function `f` that returns two parameters. After this function, I use the first parameter. I need the second one to glue things together with another function `g`. So my code would look like:

```
a, b = f()
# do stuff with a
g(b)
```

This is very repetitive, so I figured I could use something like a RAII approach. But, since I don't know when objects will die and my main goal is to get rid of the repetitive code, I used the `with` statement:

```
with F() as a:
    # do stuff with a
```

That's it. I basically created an object `F` around this function, supplying `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions (and obviously `__init__` function).

However, I still wonder whether this is the right "Pythonic" way to handle this, since a `with` statement was meant to handle exceptions. Especially this `__exit__` function has three arguments, which I don't use at the moment.

Edit (further explanations):
Whenever i call `f()` i NEED to do something with `b`. It does not matter what happened in between. I expressed it as `g(b)`. And exactly this i hide away in the with statement. So the programmer doesn't have to type `g(b)` again and again after every call of `f()`, which might get very messy and confusing, since `#do stuff with a` might get lengthy.

Comment: *Is* it very repetitive? It's not clear what the problem is, or why you thought a context manager was the best solution. If you're using that code a lot, make it a function with parameters `a` and `b`. If the bit in the middle changes, so you think you can't extract it, then add a new parameter that's a function to call with `a` before calling `g` (note that functions are first class in Python). Could you give a less abstract example of what you're trying to achieve? What does `g` *do*?

Comment: Can you explain how it is repetitive exactly? Also, how you are currently using `b` in your with statement? Personally, I prefer using `with` for things that look like resources. The other alternative is using decorators.

Comment: What exactly is `g`? Should it still happen if an exception is thrown? If it shouldn't happen, should some other sort of cleanup happen instead?

Comment: I extended my explanations. `g` is necessary, no matter what. Yet currently i have no exceptions AT ALL.

Comment: Well, you're still not explaining what these `f` and `g` are, but from what information you've given us, that sounds like a fairly standard case for a context manager.

Comment: @user2357112 That's what i wanted to hear :)
`f` prepare stuff, so i can do things with a, which it returns. `g` cleans up after things were done. Yes that should be a context manager. I just wanted to make sure, since i am still new to python and sick of solutions which somewhat work, but there are better/cleaner/readable ways of doing it in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more pythonic way of doing it would be to use the `contextlib` module. You can do away with rolling out your own class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

def g(x):
    print "printing g(..):", x

def f():
    return "CORE", "extra"

@contextmanager
def wrap():
    a, b = f()
    try:
        yield a
    except Exception as e:
        print "Exception occurred", e
    finally:
        g(b)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with wrap() as x:
        print "printing f(..):", x
        raise Exception()
```

Output:

```
$ python temp.py
printing f(..): CORE
Exception occurred
printing g(..): extra
```

Comment: I think you stuck the `@contextmanager` decorator on the wrong function.

Comment: yep, that's what i wanted. But if i (in future) need to handle exceptions, i need my own fancy class with exit and entry function, right?

Comment: Nope. Check my update above. You can surround yield with try-except-finally blocks too :)

Comment: Although it makes the code read nice - it is very prone to be misunderstood, since you aren't really creating and then closing a resource. Not wure I would go that way tbh.

Answer (score 1):

For someone else reading your code (or you in 6 months time), a context manager probably will imply the creation/initialisation and closure/deletion of a resource, and I would be very wary of re-purposing the idiom.

You could use composition, rather than a context manager:

```
def func(a, b):
    # do stuff with a & optionally b

def new_f(do_stuff):
    a, b = f()
    do_stuff(a, b)
    g(b)


new_f(func)
```

Comment: This is nice but sadly not an option, since i need to be way more general. See it as complicated `do_stuff` which cannot be handled with just one fucntion

Comment: you can always pull multiple calls into a single function surely. Well named and well documented functions are better than large blocks of code.